# capacitor & voltage source power transfer

Tags: power, capacitor, ac

When I have a capacitor connected to an AC voltage source, we can get from i=C*dv/dt the current through the capacitor (therefore through the voltage source).
Than we can multiply the voltage across it with the current and we get:
Power_over_capacitor(t) = 0.5i<sub>m</sub>*v<sub>m</sub>*sin(2wt)
During half cycly it gets power from the voltage source.
I dont understand however what does the negative power mean? when the capacitor discharges - where does the power go to?
The voltage source, as far as I understand, always provide power. So how can it get the power from the capacitor and where does it go to?

[image]

Comment: *When I have a capacitor connected to an AC voltage source* How? In series? Parallel? Draw the schematic or find a suitable picture using a Google search. Realize that a capacitor is a **reactive component** and unlike a resistor (which is a resistive component) a capacitor **cannot dissipate power**. *where does the power go to?* The **energy** or **charge** (not the power!!!) flows **back into the voltage source**. A voltage source will either **deliver** or **absorb** current in order to maintain the voltage.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It may be a voltage source but it can still take reverse current and the "negative power" goes back into the voltage source because the current is reversed. In a real supply this may not be possible of course (think voltage regulator) but, in something that behaves like an ideal voltage source, then energy is returned.

Answer (score 1):

+1 to Andy.  The capacitor stores energy (e.g. \$\frac{1}{2}Cv^2)\$ during first \$\frac{1}{4}\$ cycle, then gives it up during the next \$\frac{1}{4}\$ cycle.  This is just how capacitors do business.

In this plot below (from simple simulation of your circuit) the red trace is voltage across the cap, green is power,\$v(t)\times i(t)\$.

[image]

And here is a plot of the power (blue trace) with the energy (red trace).  This is probably what @analogsystemsrf is thinking of with his answer (energy, not power).

[image]

Answer (score 0):

If I recall rightly, sin(aT) * sin(aT) is

- 0.5 [ 1 + sin (2aT) ]

so there is no negative result.

Comment: its wrong, because if the voltage over the capacitor is sin(wt), than the current is Cdv/dt = Cw*cos(wt)

Comment: I think you are thinking energy @analogsystemsrf, not power.